# Gauss law question with regard to this example

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, gauss-law

[image]

I am really confused in Gauss law.

Why do E3 and E2 pointing up? and also E1 pointing down?

The lecture note said infer from symmetry and you will get the following but I dont really understand. Could anyone explain to me? I am new to gauss law.

Comment: The "from symmetry" argument means you should think about which directions in which the electric field could point; if the field had some component along the wire, how would it "choose" between left and right? Both directions look the same and so having a field pointing either left or right would violate the left-right symmetry of the system. The only possible direction is radially outward (or radially inward).

Comment: hmm I am still lost here. Why would it violate the left right symmetry ?

Comment: See Zhengyan Shi's answer below for an explanation of rotational symmetry. For the left-right symmetry, imagine walking into the page, past the wire, and looking at it from the other side. Everything would look the same. However if there were an E field pointing left, then from inside the page it would point to the right and you would have two inconsistent solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is a representation of three dimensions on a two dimensional screen... so talking about "up" and "down" is pretty confusing. Think about it this way: if you look from the side, the coaxial cable appears to be two concentric circles right? From this perspective, the set up has ROTATIONAL symmetry(if you rotate the system around the axis, you arrive at the same configuration as before). Therefore, the E field must also follow rotational symmetry, which means that $E_1, E_2, E_3$ all point radially, and that the magnitude of E should only depend on the distance from the center (the axis).

So "radial" is all that matters. "Up" and "down" are just misconceptions due to misleading diagram..